# MAMP Pro MySQL 8 won't launch

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I just updated to mysql 8 and Mamp pro is picking up on this but the server will not start. Whenever I go to start it I get the error that MAMP is unable to start MySQL and to check the logs.

This is the output:

```
2019-05-21T23:57:19.490578Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-05-21T23:57:19.490679Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010097] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2019-05-21T23:57:19.490724Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 17688
2019-05-21T23:57:19.493916Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2019-05-21T23:57:19.870470Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2019-05-21T23:57:19.879590Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2019-05-21T23:57:19.889824Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-05-21T23:57:19.890607Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/Applications/MAMP/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-05-21T23:57:19.914763Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-05-21T23:57:20.097515Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock'
2019-05-21T23:57:24.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2019-05-21T23:57:24.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```